# Comparison of images with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to compare two images using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and display a message, 'It is the same image.' or 'Sorry , it's not the same image.'. My program always displays 'It is the same image.'.

My code is:

```
i1 = imread('001_1_1.fig');
i2 = imread('001_1_1.fig');
x1 = edge(i1,'canny');
j1 = imcrop(x1,[135 90 100 95]);
x2 = edge(i2,'canny');
g = 0;
xxx = 1;
yyy = 1;

for n = 1:1:2
    g1 = imrotate(j1,n,'bilinear','crop');
    r1 = corr2(j1,g1);
    if(xxx<r1)
    else
        xxx = r1;
    end;
end;

for n = 180:-1:178
    g1 = imrotate(j1,n,'bilinear','crop');
    r1 = corr2(j1,g1);
    if(yyy<r1)
    else
        yyy = r1;
    end;
end;

if(xxx <= yyy)
    r_corr = xxx;
else
    r_corr = yyy;
end;

j2 = imcrop(x2,[135 90 100 95]);
r = corr2(j1,j2);
if (r==1)
    disp('it is the same image')
    return;
elseif (r >= r_corr)
    disp('it is the same image')
    return;
else
    g = 1;
end;

if(g==1)
    disp('sorry, it is not the same image')
end;
```

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem ?

Answer (score 4):

You're loading two images, `i1` and `i2` using the following command

```
i1=imread('001_1_1.fig');
i2=imread('001_1_1.fig');
```

These images are the same. Therefore, the code will tell you that the two images are the same.

Answer (score 1):

x=imread('first.jpg');

y=imread('seconda.jpg');

c=isequal(x,y);

``if c==1

printf('Yes equal ');
 else printf('Not ');